# Can MCrypt check to see if the hash created was modified?

Tags: c, encryption, mcrypt

I have 2 functions one to encrypt and decrypt an array of characters (variable called: buffer), then I save the characters in a file, so I can decrypt it later on, but I noticed that if I modify any of the characters in the encrypted text, mcrypt doesn't warn any error, it just shows different crazy characters in a piece of the text and the rest looks perfect, I want it to say that the encrypted text string has an error.

Is that a way to do that?

this is not noticeable when the text is small, but since I hash texts of 168k of characters.

My variables passed to the functions: `buffer_len = 32;`  My `IV` and `key` each of them is a list of characters of 16 bits.

```
int encrypt(void* buffer, int buffer_len, char* IV, char* key, int key_len)
{
    MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", NULL, "cbc", NULL);
    int blocksize = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(td);
    int n_blocks = buffer_len / blocksize;
    int i = 0;
    if (buffer_len % blocksize != 0)
        return 1;

    mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, key_len, IV);
    for (i = 0; i < n_blocks; i++)
        mcrypt_generic(td, ((unsigned char*)buffer) + (i * blocksize), blocksize);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit(td);
    mcrypt_module_close(td);

    return 0;
}

int decrypt(void* buffer, int buffer_len, char* IV, char* key, int key_len){
    MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", NULL, "cbc", NULL);
    int blocksize = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(td);
    int n_blocks = buffer_len / blocksize;
    int i = 0;

    if (buffer_len % blocksize != 0)
        return 1;

    mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, key_len, IV);
    for (i = 0; i < n_blocks; i++)
        mdecrypt_generic(td, ((unsigned char *)buffer) + (i * blocksize), blocksize);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit(td);
    mcrypt_module_close(td);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a php page, I know that it may apply to C as well, but how is it done? could you show me an example? and why does HMAC would help it?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't even look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

The last bug fix of `mcrypt` was from 2007. Use a library that is actually maintained and use HMAC functionality to add an authentication tag (that should also provide integrity). Don't forget to include the IV in the calculation.

Comment: Could you suggest some simple ones to implement in C ?

Comment: Try the EVP API from OpenSSL.